# How would I interact with my API using html node.js eg (be able to display data in a table or update data from user side )

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have created an API that will help in getting data from a user 
using the following form

```
 <form action="/api/v1/reflections" method="post">
<input type="text" name="success" placeholder="success">
<input type="text" name="lowPoint" placeholder="lowPoint">
<input type="text" name="takeAway" placeholder="takeAway">

<input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

and it's sending data to a given API

controls
import ReflectionModel from '../models/Reflection';

```
  create(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.success && !req.body.lowPoint && !req.body.takeAway) {
      return res.status(400).send({'message': 'All fields are required'})
    }
    const reflection = ReflectionModel.create(req.body);
    return res.status(201).send(reflection);
  },
```

model

```
  constructor() {
    this.reflections = [];
  }
  create(data) {
    const newReflection = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      success: data.success || '',
      lowPoint: data.lowPoint || '',
      takeAway: data.takeAway || '',
      createdDate: moment.now(),
      modifiedDate: moment.now()
    };
    this.reflections.push(newReflection);
    return newReflection
  }
```

I was wondering how I would display data which have been entered in a table using a findall API or function

```
 findAll() {
    return this.reflections;
  }
```

I don't know if I asked my question correctly but if you can help please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that you're not familiar with **front-end** JS and some other general concepts, so I'll give you an explanation about the basics and some references to help you understand the possible approaches, so you can decide what fits best your needs.

### 1. Fetching Data

The simplest approach is to dynamically fetch data using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), rendering it in your view and using further requests to communicate with your HTTP server to update with any changes you make.

Example:

```js
// Fetching data from some generic API
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then( res => res.json() ) // Parses body into JSON
.then( userList => {
  // Selecting our table element
  let table = document.querySelector('#t1 tbody');
  
  // For each user received, add his data on table
  userList.forEach( user => {
    let rowElement = document.createElement('tr'),
        idElement = document.createElement('td'),
        nameElement = document.createElement('td')
        emailElement = document.createElement('td');
    
    idElement.innerText = user.id;
    nameElement.innerText = user.name;
    emailElement.innerText = user.email;
    
    rowElement.appendChild(idElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(nameElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(emailElement);
    
    table.appendChild(rowElement);
  });
})
```

```html
<table id="t1" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Updating information is a little bit more simple, I recommend you to take a look in Fetch API link above, they have examples about doing HTTP requests to send data through POST method.

*Obs¹: If compatibility is important, take a look in [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to achieve similar things, but with more effort*

*Obs²: You should consider learning a front-end JavaScript framework or using a library to make DOM manipulation (inserting/removing/updating/accessing HTML elements) easier.*

### 2. WebSockets

Totally a overkill, you surely don't need it (since you're building an API and this would require implementing an Web Socket server) but [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) it is, anyway.

### 3. Rendering a Template View

This approach consists in using, at your HTTP server, some **template engine** to render before you serve your HTML (or any template engine format, like [Pug](https://pugjs.org)), but after pulling data from your database.

[Here some example using Node.js + Express and Pug](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/using-template-engines.html)

*Obs¹: You could do this "manually" without using template engines, but it would greatly increase the amount of work to achieve it.*

*Obs²: Normally, in APIs this is not necessary, since the responsability of view rendering is somewhere else.*